# \subfloat not working if file has accented characters with \usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

Tags: subfloats, accents, external-files, characters

If I use \usepackage[main=english,portuguese]{babel} there is no problem with files with accented characters. But I cannot write in Portuguese.
But if I use \usepackage[portuguese]{babel} than using \subfloat I get an error message when inserting a file whose name contains accented characters (Portuguese). Would appreciate your help.

````
\documentclass{article}

%encoding
%--------------------------------------
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%--------------------------------------
%Portuguese-specific commands
%--------------------------------------
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
%--------------------------------------
%Hyphenation rules
%--------------------------------------
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\hyphenation{mate-mática recu-perar}
%-------------------------------------- I copied this preamble from https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Portugues

\usepackage[margin=4cm,left=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{grffile} %adds some support for spaces in image file names

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\vspace{2cm} %Add a 2cm space

\begin{abstract}
Este é um breve resumo do conteúdo do documento escrito em Português.
\end{abstract}

\section{Seção introdutória}
Conclusões
A 1ª parte deste trabalho está completa, com as medições feitas antes da instalação.
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat[Porto West]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{"/Users/jervell/Desktop/números sc".jpg}}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\caption{Porto routes}
\end{figure}
\end{document}```
````

Comment: I did as you suggested but didn't work. I changed the original file to "numeros sc.jpg" (and did the same in the script: \subfloat[Porto West]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{"/Users/jervell/Desktop/numeros sc".jpg}}) and it worked, but with "números sc.jpg" it doesn't

Comment: As I said, I changed to \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{/Users/jervell/Desktop/números_sc}
and it didn't work

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that you lad package `grffile`. Now I tested your MWE and it work fine. You may consider to update your LaTeX installation.

Comment: I updated to TexMac and TexShop Version 4.44 (4.44) and problem remains, and now my English only work which was working fine gives an error with 1st image whereas no error was given before